# Configure Azure Container Insights so that metrics are not sent to Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: logging, monitoring, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I am using Azure Container Insights for an AKS cluster and I want to stop all metrics / Insights metrics (Perf, InsightsMetrics) from being sent to the Log analytics workspace, but I want to continue sending Container Logs.

I still want to collect metrics, but I want them to go to the Azure Monitor rather than LAW. How can I disable all metrics sent to the Log Analytics workspace while keeping Container Logs? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the cluster -> Insights -> Monitor settings -> Edit collection settings -> Collected data (uncheck Performance)

[Aks cluster data collection rule settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evwQs.png)

This way you will turn off collecting all metrics, you can also modify the collection data interval, so the performance logs are not so expensive.